# OCI runtime create failed - copying bootstrap data to pipe caused write init-p: broken pipe

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am on Ubuntu and docker version:

```
Docker version 18.06.3-ce, build d7080c1
```

I got this error:

> OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container
>   process caused "process_linux.go:297: copying bootstrap data to pipe
>   caused \"write init-p: broken pipe\"": unknown

when I ran:

```
docker build \
  --build-arg bitbucket_pwd="$bitbucket_password" \
  --build-arg commit_datavana="$commit_sha" \
  --build-arg CACHE_BUST="$(date)" \
  -t "$name_tag" .
```

does anyone know what causes that error? Should I downgrade docker?

Comment: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/591

Comment: which version of ubuntu you are using?

Answer (score 19):

Downgrade your version from 18.06.3 to 18.06.1 and follow the instruction from this link.It will helpfull 
https://medium.com/@dirk.avery/docker-error-response-from-daemon-1d46235ff61d

this error was resolved in my ubuntu 14.04lts system

Comment: Thanks a million times for posting this, have been looking the whole day about that error message.

Comment: We're working on docker proof of concept before we move off our old machine and this was just what I needed.

Comment: Hi everyone, if you all find this answer is useful then ,kindly make it as approved answer, thanks

Answer (score 4):

upgrade your kernel to 4.x version

```
$ apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error when set very low memory limit on kubernetes `200m` instead of `200Mi` for pod :-)

```
Normal   Scheduled               <unknown>              default-scheduler                        Successfully assigned ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-controller-b979fbd5-bkl2t to worker04.cluster
Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  12m (x4 over 12m)      kubelet, worker04.cluster  Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod "ingress-nginx-controller-b979fbd5-bkl2t": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:338: getting the final child's pid from pipe caused: read init-p: connection reset by peer: unknown
Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  12m (x9 over 12m)      kubelet, worker04.cluster  Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod "ingress-nginx-controller-b979fbd5-bkl2t": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:334: copying bootstrap data to pipe caused: write init-p: broken pipe: unknown
Normal   SandboxChanged          7m45s (x284 over 12m)  kubelet, worker04.cluster  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  2m45s (x152 over 11m)  kubelet, worker04.cluster  (combined from similar events): Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to start sandbox container for pod "ingress-nginx-controller-b979fbd5-bkl2t": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:334: copying bootstrap data to pipe caused: write init-p: broken pipe: unknown
```

Answer (score 0):

The kernel version and the docker version do not match. My original kernel version and docker are:

```bash
$ uname -a
Linux cn0314000510l 5.4.0-42-generic #46~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 07:21:24 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ sudo docker --version
Docker version 20.10.7, build 20.10.7-0ubuntu5~18.04.3
```

Then roll back the docker version and solve it:

```bash
$ docker --version
Docker version 18.09.9, build 039a7df9ba
```